# How to transform data frames into one big dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a program (code below) that gives me for each file in a folder a data frame. In the data frame are the Quarters in the Year from the file and the counts (how often the quarters occurs in the file). An output for one file in the loop look for example like:

```
2008Q4    230
2009Q1    186
2009Q2    166
2009Q3    173
2009Q4    246
2010Q1    341
2010Q2    336
2010Q3    200
2010Q4    748
2011Q1    625
2011Q2    690
2011Q3    970
2011Q4    334
2012Q1    573
2012Q2     53
```

How can I create a big data frame where the counts for the quarters are summed up for all files in the folder?

```
path = "crisisuser"
os.chdir(path)
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format("csv"))]
os.chdir("..")
for i in result:
    df = pd.read_csv("crisisuser/"+i)
    df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.time, freq='Q')
    df=df['quarter'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need append all `Series` to list, then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and `sum` per index values:

```
out = []
for i in result:
    df = pd.read_csv("crisisuser/"+i)
    df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.time, freq='Q')
    out.append(df['quarter'].value_counts().sort_index())

s = pd.concat(out).sum(level=0)
```