# How to plot a data frame from terminal?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe as an output in my terminal.
It looks like

```
2008Q1     503836
2008Q2     485872
2008Q3     686549
2008Q4     777268
2009Q1    1006589
2009Q2     849238
2009Q3     906675
2009Q4     973586
2010Q1    1090196
2010Q2    1029980
2010Q3     997876
2010Q4    1044607
2011Q1    1309266
2011Q2    1228180
2011Q3    1234710
2011Q4    1049315
2012Q1     716983
2012Q2     956271
2012Q3     788875
2012Q4     712312
2013Q1     658456
2013Q2     898281
2013Q3     822454
2013Q4     781709
2014Q1     854939
2014Q2     785794
2014Q3     724475
2014Q4     663736
2015Q1     746625
2015Q2     688598
2015Q3     633296
2015Q4     578003
2016Q1     603079
2016Q2     550575
2016Q3     482792
2016Q4     454369
2017Q1     490807
2017Q2     454263
```

The program had a long runtime and I forgot to add a plot command in the end of the code. Is there way to plot the data frame afterwards? Or can I save the data frame and then plot it?

Answer (score 0):

So if creatting this DataFrame is really long process, I suggest to save `DataFrame` to csv or pickle by [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html).

Then in second step create DataFrame by `read_csv` or [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html) and processing - ploting or similar.

All together with [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56276511/2901002):

```
out = []
for i in result:
    #use parameter usecols for filter only necessary column(s)
    df = pd.read_csv("crisisuser/"+i, usecols=['time'])
    out.append(df)
```

Alternative in list comprehension:

```
out = [pd.read_csv("crisisuser/"+i, usecols=['time']) for i in result]
```

Then join all together and if necessary write to file:

```
df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('big_file.csv', ignore_index=True)
```

Create DataFrame from file and processing:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('big_file.csv')
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.time, freq='Q')
s = df['quarter'].value_counts().sort_index()

s.plot()
```

Comment: And where do I have to write this command `DataFrame.to_csv `?

Comment: @Torb - Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once the dataframe is printed out on the terminal and not saved you cannot plot it naturally in some way.

Since you said, you have a long runtime and presumably do not want to run the code again, you can copy the console output as you pasted it in your question and paste and save it in a `*.txt` file `my_txt.txt`. That file can easily be read by `pandas` without any manual changes of the format (assuming that the format in the question is exactly the one of the console)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = pd.read_csv(r'L:\Stackoverflow\my_txt.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['A', 'B'])

>>> a.plot(x='A', y='B')    # You can e.g. plot the second column vs. the first one
```

This gives[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I plot the first column as the x-axis and the second as the y-axis?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.plot` supports also plotting columns against each other. I edited my answer accordingly